# Iterate through Nested array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a nested array on this link [Array Sample](https://pastebin.com/83kPE4sr)

I am using code below to parse this, but second and beyond depth it's returning nothing. However tried with recursive function.

```
printAllValues($ArrXML);

function printAllValues($arr) {
    $keys = array_keys($arr);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        echo $keys[$i] . "$i.{<br>";
        foreach($arr[$keys[$i]] as $key => $value) {
            if(is_array($value))
            {
                printAllValues($value);
            }
            else
            {
            echo $key . " : " . $value . "<br>";        
           }
        }
        echo "}<br>";
    }
}
```

What I am doing Wrong? Please help.

Comment: $key isn't an array, maybe $value is one

Comment: Sorry!! this was a typo mistake at the time of post. I have corrected, but still not working. Edited above is my final code and I want to iterate the complete array with key value pair dynamically

Comment: Please provide all the info needed to solve the problem **in the question** - external links can change at any time, making the question unreliable

Comment: It's an object, not an array.

Comment: @Cristik Size of given Array is large and was not able to post it here. That's why I provided it over external link. Is there is a way to put it here?

Comment: @Holger you are right. It's an Object that I want to iterate. Please guide. The code above is working for 1st level only. What part I need to change for making it recursive.

Comment: You should use `is_object($value)` to test for objects. You can also do `printAllValues($value)` on objects.

Comment: I changed the code as below:

Comment: if(is_object($value))
                                        {
                                            printAllValues($value);
                                        }

Comment: Getting Error: Warning</b>:  array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in. Actually I am new to PHP. Can you give me a piece of code that can help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version of J. Litvak's answer that works with SimpleXMLElement objects.

```
function show($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (!empty($value->children())) {
            show($value);
        } else {
            echo 'key=' . $key . ' value=' . $value. "<br>";
        }
    }
}

show($ArrXML);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recurcive function to print all values:

```
function show($array) {
    foreach( $array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            show($value);
        } else{
            echo 'key=' . $key . ' value=' . $value. "<br>";
        }
    }
}

show($ArrXML);
```

Comment: It's not working. Have you tested with the sample provided in my question? The code I am using is returning me the values but not beyond level 1